# chef server webui disable signup

Tags: chef-infra

I started playing with chef-client/server and I installed my own server.
I also installed the webui and found out that anybody can create a user, an organisation and then use my own instance for their things.

How can I disable the signup form? Which config in /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config file is [manage.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_manage.html). Set `disable_sign_up true`.